# Connecting Power BI to access database over network

Tags: ms-access, networking, vba, powerbi

I have a database that is stored on my local machine. I would like users on my network to access that database through power bi.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You could use the access options to export to SharePoint or MS SQL Server. There might a little bit of rework on forms or reports, but at that point access is just the front end and you have a backend  data source that is more friendly to business intelligence data sharing.

Comment: I don’t want to have to export every time I need the data tho.

Comment: You don’t need to. It’s a one time deal. Access will connect directly to the external data source.

Comment: Might be worthwhile https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54255

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ways-to-share-an-access-desktop-database-03822632-da43-4d8f-ba2a-68da245a0446

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just put the Access file on a network share which is accessible to all your users? By itself it should work, if all users have access to the network share.

Comment: You are using power BI right now with access, right? If not, then I would first ask how to do that. Once you have that answer, then simply placing the access accDB file in a older that all usres can see should then just work fine. So it not clear if your question is how to use Power BI with access, or how to share the database for use with power bi. (they are MASSIVE different questions here).

Comment: The second link I shared gives you pros and cons for 4 options.

Answer (score 0):

Well do you use the access file now with power BI? In ALL and in EVERY case WHEN you use a access data file, you are using a full + standard + legal path name to the access file.

So, if you want users to be able to open the Access accdb file, then the accdb file has to be placed in a folder that is open for use by anyone on the network. So, if you are using power BI with Access now you note that there is a FULL + legal path name to the Access file from that power BI system.

So, if you want to pull data from Access into Excel, then the Excel user needs to be able to see the accDB file in some folder and have rights to that folder.

So, if you want to pull data from Access into Word, then the Excel user needs to be able to see the accDB file in some folder and have rights to that folder.

So, if you want to pull data from Access into "your whatever application" that is NOW connecting to Access", then the whatever application and the users all need rights to the folder where the Access accDB file resides.